# How to hover background color size from 0 to 100%

Tags: html, css

I want to add `:hover` pseudo-class to `h1`. First, `background-color` must be equal = 0% (I add a color for test, but at the end background-color will be white) then when hover to h1, `background-color` must be gray and size to `100% 100%`. I can't do that. :')

```css
.back{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: tomato;
    height: 100px;
    background-size: 0% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: 1s all;
    
}
.back:hover{
  
    background-color: gray;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    

}
```

```html
 <h1 class="back"></h1>
```

Comment: The `background-size` property specifies the size of the background images.

Comment: No, I remember! Somebody did it for an input. But I couldn't find that... :(

Comment: Please describe it better what you want. As @TechySharnav mentioned above, `background-size` specifies the size of the background images. Do you want to change the box size?

Comment: Okay. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861648/animate-an-elements-width-from-0-to-100-with-it-and-its-wrapper-being-only-a

I want to do this for background-color. ^^

Answer (score 0):

From your comment it seems you want something like this, correct me if I am wrong.

```css
.back{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100px;
    width: 0%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: 1s all;
    
}
.back:hover{
  
    background-color: gray;
    width: 250px;
    

}
```

```html
<h1 class="back">Header</h1>
```

I added a text in your `h1` tag for easier use since I suppose you do have some text in there.

Comment: Yeah! what I want is like this. But I remember border and width was same... Anyway, it is useful, also. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score -1):

**You must use "div" not h1. Also u should set the height of body to 100%, so that on hover, your div gets the fullscreen**

```css
HTML, body{
    height:100%
}

.back{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: tomato;
    height: 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: 1s all;
    
}
.back:hover{
  
    background-color: gray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    

}
```

```html
 <div class="back"></div>
```